# Get remoteAddress from https.Server#clientError in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, https

In Node.js both `http.Server` and `https.Server` emit the `clientError` event but with different arguments:
`http.Server#clientError(exception, socket)`
`https.Server#clientError(exception, securePair)`

With `securePair` being an instance of `tls.SecurePair`, `securePair.cleartext` a `tls.CleartextStream` and `securePair.encrypted` a `tls.CryptoStream`.

The question is: how do I get the address and port of the client that caused the `clientError`? In theory, this should work:
`socket = securePair.cleartext.socket;`
`console.log(socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort);`

In reality, when I try to connect to the HTTPS server using HTTP (pretending it were a HTTP server) and cancelling after a few seconds, I get a `clientError` of type `ECONNRESET`, but `socket.remoteAddress` and `socket.remotePort` are both `undefined` (even though `securePair.cleartext.socket` is indeed a `net.Socket` and not `undefined`).

Comment: That may be because the ssl handshake never completed. What happens if you really *do* connect using https and then an error happens?

Comment: By design, `tls.SecurePair.cleartext` corresponds to the pre-authentication stream and shouldn't be affected by the SSL handshake failure. In any case, I think it's entirely reasonable to expect `https.Server` to provide a way to get client address as long as a TCP connection was established.

Comment: I'm faced with the exact same problem...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, bounty did not seem to help much :-( I had to investigate this myself.

Apparently, a fix has been made (but is not yet in any released node.js) to be able to get these values even after socket has been closed: https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/8c38b07252d86f4eef91344f8df4f0c3e38bca35

A workaround is to store the address at connect time:

```
srv.on('connect', function (socket) {
  socket.stored_remoteAddress = socket.remoteAddress;
});
srv.on('clientError', function (err, socket) {
  console.log(socket.cleartext.socket.stored_remoteAddress);
}
```

This works, but is not pretty.

---

Apparently, even this does not work fully :-(

Node.js 0.11 does not emit the 'clientError' event on SSL errors (for example), so there's no way to catch the situation there.

Node.js 0.12 emits the 'clientError' event, but uses a new TLS implementation which does not have the 'cleartext' socket available anymore. I could not find any way to pass information from 'connect' event to 'clientError' event, or any way to find out that they are for the same socket (as the socket is already closed in the 'clientError' event).

So, it would seem that the only way is to wait for a new Node.js release (0.12.2 earliest, if they think this is worth a fix) and hope this gets fixed for real.

Comment: thanks for putting me on the right path. I ended up monkey-patching net.Socket with the commit you pointed to, then using tlsSocket._parent._peername to access the remote socket properties from the tls socket object. Much appreciated!